# "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string " on dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @date Datetime ='',@query nvarchar(max);
set @date   =getdate();
set @query='select * from [3].[Sync_Database_BTS].dbo.[Test] where  [Test] >=cast(date,'+ @date +' ,103) ; '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Can you please tell me what is my mistake .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `date` to `varchar` if you are using the `datetime` type in dynamic query

You cannot use `style` in `cast` function you need to use `Convert` instead.  Also you need extra single quotes around `datetime` parameter.

```
DECLARE @date  DATETIME ='',
        @query NVARCHAR(max);

SET @date = Getdate();
SET @query='select * from [3].[Sync_Database_BTS].dbo.[Test] where  [Test] >=convert(date,'''
           + Cast(@date AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''' ,103) ; '

--print @query
EXEC Sp_executesql
  @query
```

Always use **Print statement** to debug dynamic query

Comment: working,thanks but why my query does not works? what is the issue?

Comment: @King_Fisher - I added explantion

Comment: @King_Fisher, Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just because you're using a dynamic query, that doesn't prevent you from using [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and keeping everything nicely typed:

```
declare @date Datetime ='',@query nvarchar(max),@parms nvarchar(max);
set @date   =getdate();
set @query=N'select * from [3].[Sync_Database_BTS].dbo.[Test]
             where [Test] >=cast(date,@date) ; ';
set @parms = N'@date datetime';

exec sp_executesql @query,@parms,@date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @date Datetime ='',@query nvarchar(max);
set @date   =getdate();
set @query='select * from [3].[Sync_Database_BTS].dbo.[Test] where  [Test] >=convert(date,'+ @date +' ,103) ; '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @date Datetime 
,@query nvarchar(max);
set @date   =getdate()-2;
set @query='select * from [Test]  where  convert(varchar,test ,100)>=' +''''+convert(varchar,@date,100)+''''
print (@query)
exec sp_executesql @query

Comment: Hi @rajesh-yadav, could you explain a little the mistakes please?

Comment: Its Just a datatype miss match error ...I converted column and value both in varchar thats it :)

Comment: No i wanna check with date and time also,not only date

Comment: @King_Fisher check now

Answer (score 0):

try this this is working for me

```
declare @date Datetime ='',@query nvarchar(max);
set @date   = convert(Varchar(10),getdate(),126);
set @query='select * from [3].[Sync_Database_BTS].dbo.[Test] where  [Test] >= @date; '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

> if you used 126 format is default format for Sql Server